# What's the best way to store data on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, sqlite

i have made iOS apps using SQLite Database...

For this I read the guideline from Apple and found that "user can store files in the /Documents directory"

In my application, I am using single mode login. For this I am storing all user data (which are basically Sqlite db) to Documents directory. The Database is also present in the same directory which contains the details about the downloaded from web.

```
My question is,
1. Should I have to change the storing file location instead of to the Documents directory?
2. Where should my database file be placed?
3. don't want to delete database file after user deleting Apps.(if user installed again i want to show that same db)
```

If I put it Documents directory once user deleting apps from device it's removed all files.

Kindly guide me on this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In my opinion application's **Cache Directory** is best place to store dynamic content.

Answer (score 2):

1. & 2.: Using The documents directory is fine.
2. You can't retain data after an app is deleted. A better way to do this would be to have user accounts where a copy of a person's database is stored on a server.  The user would just login and download their account info if they ever reinstalled. (see Parse.com for some awesome ways to do this).

Comment: Shouldn't it Cache directory ?

Comment: @TheTiger Cache directory should be used by any data that the app can reproduce/download when it is delete after the system runs out of storage space. Any data that you can not reproduce should be stored in the Document directory. Thus any data that the user insert into a database is not reproducible by your app and should there for be stored in the documents directory.

Comment: @rckoenes - Right ... For static data we should document directory.